# Git rename initial branch: to force or not to force?

Tags: git, github

When you create a new repository called `temp` on GitHub, you are shown these instructions to follow locally:

```
echo "# temp" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:mattneub/temp.git
git push -u origin main
```

But I find in the `git branch` command, it's fine to say `-m` instead of `-M`. The former doesn't use "force"; the latter does.

So my question is: Why might GitHub be advising the use of force unnecessarily? Is it perhaps because Git itself changed recently to allow this?

Comment: Aside from the contained `--force`, this can only be speculated: "Why GitHub does something" can only be answered by them.

Comment: My guess is that they’re trying to minimize the chances of a beginner getting an error. If you run “git branch main” before “git branch -m main”, you’ll get an error.

Comment: @iBug The question is genuine. I had the impression that indeed I _did_ have to use `-M`. In fact, my notes say that I couldn't even say that until the initial branch had commits. But I just tried it and I can use `-m` whether or not the initial branch has commits. I appreciate that the GitHub part of the question runs the risk of being opinion-based, but it isn't important; what I really want to know is whether Git itself changed.

Comment: OK I see what you're asking for. I didn't start using Git until it's like 2.12 or 2.15, so I'm probably not up for answering this question.

Comment: As an added comment to this, `git branch -M` looks to rename the branch you are on to main (please do correct me if I am incorrect). But if you download git, you have the option to set your default branch name to main. So you could go on to argue that the entire line, not just the flag, is unnecessary. This looks like it just adds consistency (and also encourages that new repositories favour main as opposed to the deprecated default branch name).

Comment: @Kraigolas I think you're missing even more about the question. It's asking about `-m` vs `-M`, not whether to perform a rename or not.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, for new repositories, the presence of `--force` (or `-m` vs `-M` since `-M` is equivalent to `-m -f`) when renaming branches makes no difference.

The ability to change the name for the default branch of a new repository was only introduced in Git 2.28 (July 2020), and prior to that it was hardcoded as `master`, which is still the default value for `init.defaultBranch` if it's empty.

Git manpage states that `-f` overwrites the target branch name if it's present, and make no difference otherwise, when used to rename branches.

---

So the whole argument boils down to preferences. From my experiences, renaming branches is already a rare operation, and it's often done only when one is confident about that, so `-M` is used more often. Then it's just whoever at GitHub decided to use `-M` on their website.

Comment: Note that `--force` (instead of `-M`, `-D`, etc) for `git branch` is missing in some really ancient versions of Git. (As bad as the commands are today in terms of inconsistency with flags, they used to be much worse!)

Comment: @torek At least I tested Git 1.8 and it's there. I doubt those "superior antiques" would make any real productivity nowadays.

Comment: The 1.8 documentation doesn't mention combining `-f` with `-m`. There was a bug fix to 1.7.10 where `git branch -f` crashed because `-f` meant *create branch* and with the lack of a name, Git followed the NULL pointer; see commit 5cd75c7d8da8971. ... Aha, commit 356e91f made `-f -m` equivalent to `-M`, first released in 2.3.0, but went undocumented until 2.5.0. (Note: some CentOS systems still come with Git 1.7 and 1.8. I find this a bit inexplicable...)

Answer (score 1):

After some research and experimentation, I have to conclude that the GitHub folks are probably just playing very safe.

s iBug says, the `git init -b` command and the `init.defaultBranch` configuration are relatively recent, and are part of the push away from `master` as a default. `git branch -m`, on the other hand, has been around a long time.

There are times when `git branch -m` can fail; it isn't terribly likely, though. The main cases seem to be:

- You are altering the case of the branch name.
- You are giving the branch a name that already exists.

When you are first creating a repo locally, neither of those is likely to be the case. So GitHub's advice to use `-M` is probably overkill, but it is broader than `-m` so it's a way of taking no chances.

Comment: Did you see my comment on the question? I never got feedback from you on it, but this answer is similar. BTW, I think the background for why the command is used (first 2 paragraphs) adds unnecessary complexity.