# Git seems to automatically push to master branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

New to coding so I've been trying to find my way around git.

Every time I seem to want to push a commit from my terminal it seems to automatically push to the master branch rather than the main. Now I know that I can just change the branch in Github to make master the main one I'm just curious as to why this is happening. I tried "git fetch" "git reset --hard origin/master" as well as trying to rename the branch to no avail, even switching branch like I said before it would push to the main branch on it's own.

Here is a run down of how I go about it maybe I'm doing something wrong, first "git init", then "Git add .", then "git commit -m "message", then "git remote add origin master" then I push. Everything goes through fine except on github I'm now asked if I want to pull the commit and there are no changes to see. I included pictures with an example because I'm not sure I'm explaining everything properly. As I said tried to figure this one out on my own but I'm most likely not really understanding the origin of the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzgA3.png)

Thanks for any pointer or tips you could provide to fix this.

**Update**: so I updated my git and I now get a new error that I don't understand :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBpDS.png)

Trying git force

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYIJs.png)

Found the solution to my problem thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `git init` puts you on the unborn `master` branch instead of `main`, and you wish it were `main`, you have many options:

- Update your Git. Newer Git versions default to `main`.
- Or else, change your `init.defaultBranch` config.

  ```
    git config --global init.defaultBranch main
  ```
- Or, just say `git init -b main` instead.
- Or, after `git init`, say `git branch -M main`.

Comment: And see my article: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Comment: Nice answer. Not sure if it was intentional, but the use of `-M` instead of `-m` in the last command is causing an infinite loop paradox in my head that I hope others might enjoy as well. :D

Comment: @TTT see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552802/git-rename-initial-branch-to-force-or-not-to-force

Comment: alright so I think the issue is that I was out of date now however I get a new error " Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details."  Thank you for the help though!

Comment: Wow- that's too funny. I basically had the exact thought reading your answer as you did when you read the GitHub docs. I'm shocked that question was DV'd- it's a legit question.

Comment: @Dan that error means your local and remote branches have diverged, meaning they both have commits that the other doesn't. If you just created a brand new repo in GitHub and you don't care about anything out there yet, then you probably just need to force push. If you search for that error you'll find *many* new Git users have the same question.

Comment: @TTT yup that's exactly what I tried, git push origin master -f, and other variations, doesn't seem to work, I get a src refspec master doesn not match any, error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Jayzheh/Thankyoustack.git' (I added the piture as well) but i'll kepp looking into it haha

Comment: You cannot push _anything_ until you have commits to push. If you have never said `git add` and `git commit`, there is no actual branch (it is, as I said in my answer, unborn). However, that is not what you asked. I can only repeat, read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Comment: @matt i'm not sure I get what you mean, in all instances I have something to add and commit however I keep getting the same error messages as shown on the last image. Thank you for the link! that's my best shot so i'll take a look right now